# multiple Stored procedures dependent on one another. Should be done in code or Stored procedure?

Tags: .net, sql, c#-4.0, optimization

I was trying to decide whether or not I should try to consolidate my stored procedures in my database or do it code. Basically, I have one table (Analytics) that has a foriegn key to the other table (Urls). When a user accesses certain pages, the first table will try to create the entry. In the stored procedure for this table (Analytics), if the row already exists, it will update otherwise, create the row. I was thinking of sending back the ID and then updating the other table. OR I could update the other table in the same stored procedure. There will also be 2 other tables that in the same page hit will do something similar.

I'm conflicted because my object oriented side wants each stored procedure to only do one thing, but I know that this will be happening on each page and want to get what I can out of optimization if possible.

What are thoughts on the speed difference on multiple calls versus one call to the Database. is it really going to cause an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are thoughts on the speed difference on multiple calls versus one call to the Database. is it really going to cause an issue?

Yes, it certainly could.

For each database call there are connection overheads, network IO overheads and extra work for the database server and client - these are slow. Additionally, structuring stored procedures in such a way can easily lead you into an [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

In general, if you can structure things so that you do as much as possible in *one* query, your database and application would be faster and more responsive, as expensive and slow resource usage is kept to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you Oden. So the best way is to get away from the Object Oriented thinking and have the stored procedure do all the inserts and updates for you in one fail swoop from what you are saying correct? Less calls / overhead. The only concern I guess that I have is that although it is less overhead.. does the stored procedure become harder to read as well as harder to name if it does a bunch of things? Also What are your thoughts on Stored procedures that call other stored procedure to keep things seperated still?

Comment: Well, you need to consider readability and the option of a SP doing too much as well. There is no one right answer here - you need to weigh things out and see how they pan out in production. There are patterns like CQRS that can make things a bit simpler on this front.

Comment: As for SPs calling SPs - this can become a tangled horrible mess in the long run (how many levels do you allow? how do you ensure changes to one SP won't ripple through? etc...).

Comment: The other thing about having SPs calling SPs is that while you can do that, there are some limitations. Primarily, if you are going more than 2 deep and each SP returns a resultset you want to capture via `Insert Into ... Exec`, then that will fail after the second level. For some reason MS SQL will not allow it. To clarify, you can have SP A use `Insert Into ... Exec B`, but you can't then have SP B use `Insert Into ... Exec C`.